# Facebook share button to post multiple times from the same url

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Does Facebook have a share button similar to "Tweet". The goal is to allow users to share the content of the webpage(with the same url) multiple times to their walls. The content of the webpage changes but the url doesn't. I know tweet will work in this situation, but I couldn't find anything on Facebook social plugins that will allow me to do that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the simple share or like button but use dynamic og meta tags?

Comment: How would that help? I still can't click the like twice.